# How to write and take the right values needed from a csv file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, fopen

Previously I had two tables.
I have a php script to copy the contents of one table one to table 2, to identify the ids which are copied I made a csv file to check for the last row inserted id like below

```
 "Date",lastid(int)
```

Previously I was checking the last id using the index of csv by using fopen as 0 and 1.

But now I have another table 3 to copy  to table 2 and the process is same. but When i write for the new table it gets overwritten so I cant identifiy for the previous table. If i append it the file will get  extended. Is there any way to put the table 1 contents in the first line and table two last id in the second line as

```
  "Date",lastid(int), // for t1 copied to t2
  "Date",lastid(int)  // for t3 copied to t2
```

and taking 0, 1 for table 1 and 2,3 for table 2. Even when table 2 is done  first.

```
public function writeNumberOfRowsCopiedForTable2FromTable1($row_write)
{
    $file = fopen('rowsCopied.csv', 'w+');
    fputcsv($file, $row_write);
    fclose($file);

}
```

calling it by

```
writeNumberOfRowsCopiedForTable2FromTable1([$this->global_date, $last_row_copied]);
```

getting values for inserted values in t2 from t1

```
 public function getLastRowCopied()
{
    $end_row_id = 0;
    if (file_exists('rowsCopied.csv')) {
        $handle       = fopen('rowsCopied.csv', 'r');
        $data         = fgetcsv($handle);
        $end_row_id += intval($data[1]);
        $this->global_date = $data[0];
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $end_row_id;

}
```

Hope I explained the question.
Someone knows the answer?

Comment: Can you include your current code, it will help.  Although I'm not sure of this as a good method to do what you want.

Comment: @NigelRen I have updated with the code. Could you check it?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a couple of methods which should do what your after.  You will need to integrate them with how you currently use them, but this is just so I can test them for myself.

Each method takes a `$rowNumber` parameter, this is the row in the stored file that you want to set/get the value for.  In the code it adjusts it, so row 1 is actually element 0 of the array.  I've used `file()` to read the whole file in and then get/set the row your interested in.  In the `writeNumberOfRowsCopied` method it then uses `file_put_contents()` to write the whole file out in one go (imploding the lines of the file).

```
function writeNumberOfRowsCopied($rowNumber, $row_write)
{
    $fileName = 'rowsCopied.csv';
    $file = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $file[$rowNumber-1] = implode(",", $row_write);
    file_put_contents($fileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $file));
}

function getLastRowCopied($rowNumber)
{
    $fileName = 'rowsCopied.csv';
    $file = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $row = explode(",", $file[$rowNumber-1]);
    return (int)$row[1];
}
writeNumberOfRowsCopied(2, ["aa", 22121]);
print_r(getLastRowCopied(2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your  answer :) I will check if that works for me.